# Centos 7 Install GraphicsMagick

Tags: centos

I try to install GraphicsMagick 1.3.22 on Centos 7 .

For installing GraphicsMagick  i followed this tutorial : https://gist.github.com/paul91/9008409

Here is things  i did :

```
# Install build dependencies
yum install -y gcc libpng libjpeg libpng-devel libjpeg-devel ghostscript libtiff libtiff-devel freetype freetype-devel

# Get GraphicsMagick source
wget ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/1.3/GraphicsMagick-1.3.22.tar.gz
tar zxvf GraphicsMagick-1.3.22.tar.gz

# Configure and compile
cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.22
./configure --enable-shared
make
make install
```

after runing `make install` command i get this message and GraphicsMagick is not runing.

```
Makefile:9955: warning: overriding recipe for target `PerlMagick/Magick.pm'
Makefile:4520: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `PerlMagick/Magick.pm'
make  install-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sasha/GraphicsMagick-1.3.22'
Makefile:9955: warning: overriding recipe for target `PerlMagick/Magick.pm'
Makefile:4520: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `PerlMagick/Magick.pm'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sasha/GraphicsMagick-1.3.22'
Makefile:9955: warning: overriding recipe for target `PerlMagick/Magick.pm'
Makefile:4520: warning: ignoring old recipe for target `PerlMagick/Magick.pm'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   magick/libGraphicsMagick.la Magick++/lib/libGraphicsMagick++.la wand/libGraphicsMagickWand.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c magick/.libs/libGraphicsMagick.so.3.14.0 /usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.so.3.14.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.so.3.14.0': Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/GraphicsMagick-1.3.22'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/GraphicsMagick-1.3.22'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

i want know what is problem .
thanks in advance

---

Update : 
i am not using root user.

Comment: make install is supposed to be run as root because it needs to copy file in system directories usually. You didn't give details about the user you used.

Comment: @pat i am not usign root user , before start installing i switched to my user with this command `su myuser`

Comment: yes compilation (configure/make) is supposed to be done as a regular user, but you have to make install as root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configure` and `make` are not supposed to be run as root user, but `make install`, as it's supposed to copy files in the system dirs is. Otherwise you will get errors like yours

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.so.3.14.0': Permission denied
```

So please run make install as root.